# Get average time of HH:MM format hours from array in php

Tags: php

I want to know the average of these hours. These are calculated hours taken by a task. How can I get the average time?
sum of these hours is 1640:15.
When I divide these hours by count of array I get 11.388888888889 which I don't know is right or wrong.

These hours are calculated hour like one task takes 260:50 Hrs.

If there is any similar question available please tell me. Thanks

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09:00
    [1] => 01:08
    [2] => 07:26
    [3] => 69:25
    [4] => 00:20
    [5] => 09:04
    [6] => 03:26
    [7] => 06:54
    [8] => 08:24
    [9] => 01:37
    [10] => 10:09
    [11] => 02:56
    [12] => 06:23
    [13] => 06:23
    [14] => 08:50
    [15] => 06:22
    [16] => 06:21
    [17] => 06:16
    [18] => 09:00
    [19] => 06:14
    [20] => 06:14
    [21] => 06:13
    [22] => 06:12
    [23] => 06:08
    [24] => 06:08
    [25] => 06:08
    [26] => 06:07
    [27] => 09:00
    [28] => 01:01
    [29] => 01:01
    [30] => 01:00
    [31] => 00:59
    [32] => 07:54
    [33] => 07:54
    [34] => 07:52
    [35] => 07:52
    [36] => 00:58
    [37] => 00:57
    [38] => 08:00
    [39] => 08:00
    [40] => 07:58
    [41] => 07:56
    [42] => 07:56
    [43] => 260:46
    [44] => 01:04
    [45] => 01:04
    [46] => 01:05
    [47] => 01:07
    [48] => 07:26
    [49] => 09:00
    [50] => 142:54
    [51] => 59:19
    [52] => 13:09
    [53] => 17:11
    [54] => 00:53
    [55] => 54:15
    [56] => 62:52
    [57] => 06:35
    [58] => 04:44
    [59] => 05:22
    [60] => 05:22
    [61] => 05:21
    [62] => 05:14
    [63] => 05:13
    [64] => 05:12
    [65] => 05:12
    [66] => 05:11
    [67] => 05:06
    [68] => 05:08
    [69] => 05:08
    [70] => 05:10
    [71] => 05:07
    [72] => 05:06
    [73] => 05:03
    [74] => 05:03
    [75] => 04:59
    [76] => 04:58
    [77] => 05:00
    [78] => 02:01
    [79] => 02:02
    [80] => 02:02
    [81] => 02:02
    [82] => 02:03
    [83] => 02:04
    [84] => 02:05
    [85] => 02:05
    [86] => 02:07
    [87] => 02:08
    [88] => 02:08
    [89] => 02:09
    [90] => 02:09
    [91] => 02:09
    [92] => 02:10
    [93] => 02:11
    [94] => 02:11
    [95] => 06:21
    [96] => 02:16
    [97] => 04:05
    [98] => 09:00
    [99] => 09:00
    [100] => 00:34
    [101] => 03:13
    [102] => 03:46
    [103] => 00:16
    [104] => 02:35
    [105] => 01:19
    [106] => 04:32
    [107] => 00:30
    [108] => 03:36
    [109] => 06:53
    [110] => 02:41
    [111] => 135:58
    [112] => 01:35
    [113] => 09:04
    [114] => 00:11
    [115] => 07:39
    [116] => 00:14
    [117] => 16:00
    [118] => 94:00
    [119] => 03:40
    [120] => 00:21
    [121] => 03:47
    [122] => 02:00
    [123] => 06:54
    [124] => 74:12
    [125] => 00:12
    [126] => 00:39
    [127] => 03:37
    [128] => 00:05
    [129] => 00:04
    [130] => 06:50
    [131] => 05:03
    [132] => 53:44
    [133] => 01:38
    [134] => 00:16
    [135] => 44:18
    [136] => 00:01
    [137] => 10:06
    [138] => 00:35
    [139] => 02:22
    [140] => 01:00
    [141] => 00:04
    [142] => 00:21
    [143] => 00:57
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time average in hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534074/time-average-in-hours)

Comment: In my question, the hours are calculated hours like "this task take 260:46 Hrs time" so how I will get the average of all hours.

Comment: *I get 11.38 which I don't if it's right or wrong* (looks about right from a quick scan down) but why don't you try with only a couple of values, eg `00:05, 00:10, 00:15` and see what your average calculation is?

Comment: I have tried this way and the answer was correct for hours that are under 24 but if the calculated hour is greater than 24 the logic won't work correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your hours can exceed 24, you can't use `strtotime` based methods to convert them. One way to do the math is to explode each value on `:` to separate the hours and minutes and sum the total minutes. You can then compute the average minutes and output that in the required format:

```
$total_minutes = 0;
foreach ($times as $time) {
    list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time);
    $total_minutes += $hours * 60 + $minutes;
}
$average_minutes = $total_minutes / count($times);
echo "Average time is " . round($average_minutes / 60, 2) . " hour\n";
$average_hours = floor($average_minutes / 60);
$average_minutes = $average_minutes % 60;
echo "Average time is " . str_pad($average_hours, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":" . str_pad($average_minutes, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
Average time is 11.39 hours
Average time is 11:23
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EZgJQ)

Comment: Thanks [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) this looks fine and working for me.